# I can't display an error message in my password change form with Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I use the built in PasswordChangeForm class but I rewrite the html of the template because I don't like the default placement of error messages (strangely located between the "new password" field and the "new password confirmation" field).

My form works when I correctly fill in old and new passwords. Otherwise, the page reloads without indication.

When it works I am redirected to a "PasswordChangeDoneView" page.
Ideally, I would prefer not to be redirected but it's less important.

**url.py :**

```
path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name = 'password_change'),
path('password_change_done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name = 'password_change_done'),
```

**views.py :**

```
@login_required
def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password_form = PasswordChangeForm(instance = request.user, data = request.POST)
        if password_form.is_valid():
            password_form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, password_form.user)  # <-- keep the user loged after password change
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!', extra_tags='safe')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong', extra_tags='safe')
    else:
        password_form = PasswordChangeForm(instance = request.user)
    return render(request, 'registration/password_change_form.html', {'password_form': password_form})
```

**password_change_form.html :**

```
<form action='.' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <p>
        <label for='id_old_password'>Old password:</label>
        <input type='password' name='old_password' autofocus='' required='' id='id_old_password'>
    </p>
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <p class='border-alert {{ message.tags }}'>{{ message|safe }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %} 
    <p>
        <label for='id_new_password1'>New password:</label>
        <input type='password' name='new_password1' required='' id='id_new_password1'>
        <span class='helptext'></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='id_new_password2'>New password confirmation:</label>
        <input type='password' name='new_password2' required='' id='id_new_password2'>
    </p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type='submit' value='Change you password' class='btn w100'></p>
</form>
```

The Django PasswordChangeForm class is visible at the bottom of this page : https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py

EDIT :

I've pretty much solved my problem with the following changes to my code :

Now in my **views.py** I have this :

```
@login_required
def password_change(request):
    password_form = PasswordChangeForm(instance = request.user, data = request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if password_form.is_valid():
            password_form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, password_form.user)  # <-- keep the user loged after password change
    return render(request, 'registration/password_change_form.html', {'password_form': password_form})
```

And in my **template** I use this :

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.errors }}
{% endfor %}
```

I do not use the {% if messages %} part in my template anymore.

The error messages are the "Django built-in provided" and when I have correctly filled the inputs I am redirected to my "change password success view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happening,

In your views you are not redirecting to any other page. That means you are requesting the same form again. As this is a form get function, so your success message is always False.

Then you can do one of these things,

1. Add form.errors. As you are using Django's inbuilt password reset form. It will show error if your password did not match or your old password is incorrect etc.

   Redirect to profile page or any other page. Add the message tag there. It will work perfectly in that page.
2. (Not tried by me, usually I redirect to profile page and show message there but you can try if you want, not sure will it work),

   ```
   def password_change(request):
       form = #add form
       success = False
       if request.method == 'POST':
           if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           update_session_auth_hash(request, password_form.user)
           form = #add form
           success = True
       return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
   ```

Comment: I didn't succeed when I tried to add {{ forms.error }} but on the page in the Django web site that was describing the use of the {{ forms.error }} in the templates there was a part about {{ field.errors }} [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) that worked for me.